Parametrization of elliptic curve with differential equation $(x,y)=(f(x),f'(x))$ involving Lambert $W$ function
For non-zero complex $A$, define the curve over the complex numbers
$C: x^2 y^2-A x-y=0$. $C$ is an elliptic curve.
$C$ has the differential equation parametrization $(x,y)=(f(x),f'(x))$
where
$$ f(x)=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}} {\left(\operatorname{W}({-e^{\left(3 \, A {\left(2 \, c_{1} - x\right)} - 1\right)}}) + 2\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} \operatorname{W}({-e^{\left(3 \, A {\left(2 \, c_{1} - x\right)} - 1\right)}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2 \, A^{\frac{1}{3}}} $$
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}} A^{\frac{2}{3}} \operatorname{W}({-e^{\left(6 \, A c_{1} - 3 \, A x - 1\right)}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}{{\left(\operatorname{W}({-e^{\left(6 \, A c_{1} - 3 \, A x - 1\right)}}) + 2\right)}^{\frac{2}{3}}}
$$
where $W$ is Lambert W function.

Q1 Is this result known?


Q2 Is $f(x)$ related to Weierstrass elliptic function
${\displaystyle \wp }$?

$C$ is birationally equivalent to short Weierstrass model
$v^2=u^3+a_4 u + a_6$ where $u,v$ are rational functions of $f(x),f'(x)$.
$f$ in machine readable form:
f=(lambert_w(-e^(-3* A* (x - 2*c_1) - 1))^(1/3)* (lambert_w(-e^(-3* A* (x - 2*c_1) - 1)) + 2)^(1/3))/(2^(2/3)* A^(1/3))

Observe that Lambert $W$ has branches.
Complex plot of $f(x)$:

